# Retrieving Data from Stored Procedure in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have following two model classes

```
public partial class Items {
    public Items() {
        this.Items_RATINGS = new HashSet<Items_RATINGS>();
    }

    public int ITEMID { get; set; }
    public string ITEMNAME { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Items_RATINGS> Items_RATINGS { get; set; }
}

public partial class Items_RATINGS
{
    public int ItemsID { get; set; }
    public byte ItemsRATING { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
 }
```

I've also created stored procedure to review average rating

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING
@ITEMID INT
AS
 BEGIN
   SELECT AVG(OVERALLRATING) AS OVERALLRATING FROM ITEMS_RATINGS WHERE ITEMID = @ITEMID GROUP BY ITEMID
END
GO
```

In model class, I have added

```
public virtual ICollection<GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING_Result> GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING { get; set; }
```

In the controller calls, I tried adding

```
return View(db.Items.Include(c => c.GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING).ToList());
```

However, I'm not getting the value. Its throwing an error.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[stored]` and `[procedure]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[stored-procedures]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the stored procedure to your edmx model

**Here is how to do it**

1- Open your edmx file

2- Next right click anywhere on the Edmx designer and choose Add > Function Import.

3- This will bring up the wizard for adding Function. Choose the procedure you want to add and choose the return type .

4- Then you can call your stored procedure as a CLR method from your dbcontext.

Comment: Thanks. Did like you said. I'm now getting following error Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ItemModel.ITEMS' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING'.

Comment: REMOVE GET_ITEM_AVERAGERATING FROM YOU ITEMS CLASS.


After you add your SP to the edmx model, it will generate a proxy method in yout dbcontext class. So remove this navigation property in ur Items class and call your stored procedure from your dcontext object.

Comment: What type of model that you want to return to your view?

Comment: I want the Items model to be returned. I want to display the overall rating for that item

Comment: nice to here this. Welcome :)